# MySQL Multiple Table Query and Results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query multiple tables and trying to display the results as follows...

Tables...

```
news
id    title      news_datestamp
1      news 1       01/01/2001
2      news 2       01/05/2001

articles    title          articles_datstamp
1            article 1         01/04/2001
2            article 2         01/06/2001
```

I'm trying to get a single script to display the results as...

```
News 1 01/01/2001
Article 1 01/04/2001
News 2 01/05/2001
Article 2 01/06/2001
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Alright,also post your tries.

Comment: It looks like one of two things could be going on here. Do you want all of the items sorted ascending by `datestamp`, or do you want them sorted primarily by `id` ascending and then alternating between `News` and `Article`?

Comment: How do these two tables of data relate to each other?  Do you need to add a column (i.e., foreign key) to one or both of these tables to account for the relationship between news items and articles?  That would make what you appear to be trying to do easier.

Comment: Using UNION will show you all the news and right after all the articles, not in between as you show in your example, however if you order that by date then you may have articles and news mixed. If articles belongs to news then you must edit your schema to have a relational one (as James says) using foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simple use a `Union` to merge results in a subselect and sort the final table:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, title, news_datestamp AS datestamp, "news" AS type FROM news
  UNION ALL
  SELECT articles AS id, title, article_datestamp AS datestamp, "article" AS type FROM articles
) AS temptable
ORDER BY datestamp
```

The `type` column will help you to identify id references later.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want a union of the `news` and `article` tables.

```
SELECT * FROM
  ( SELECT title,
           news_datestamp AS datestamp
      FROM news
     UNION ALL
    SELECT title,
           article_datestamp AS datestamp
     FROM articles
    ) AS everything
   ORDER BY datestamp, title
```